# set iframe in article in joomla

Tags: iframe, joomla

I am new in joomla. I am using joomla 1.5.26. I have created one article and try to place an iframe in that article in html mode. But when I try to save its becoming blank. How to solve this issue. Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which text editor are you using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's  happened because of text filtering. To prevent Joomla from stripping HTML from your content see below (Note: Be careful while settings in production server):

1. Go to the Article Manager.
2. Select ” Options ” (the button on the top right).
3. Under Text Filters options, choose: Filter groups: select the groups that are allowed to    use HTML code, e.g. SuperAdministrator Filter type: Whitelist / no filtering.

also check your editor settings.