# Iframe Article issues inside Joomla Version 1.5.0

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5

Basically We are new to joomla.

We have created an article and put a iframe tag inside of it but it happens that this page permission error shows after saving the article.

[image]

We have tried this [set iframe in article in joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080468/set-iframe-in-article-in-joomla) but we cannot find the options button not sure where it is located.

Updating of joomla to the latest version is not an option now.

Thanks Guys

Comment: First, you need to turn off the wysiwyg editor for anything like this. Second check to see if there is a wrapper module available. If there is make a module instance with url you want and use loadposition to embed in your article.  Alternatively if you only want an iframe but no content, do not use an article at all, that is whey there is a wrapper menu type ... it makes the iframe for you.

Comment: Hi Elin Thanks for this. We'll give a try

Comment: another option is to allow the iframe tag within jce editor. Refer to their forum

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using JCE Editor, you might want to consider their iFrames plugin: https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/downloads/plugins/add-ons  (it is commercial)

Comment: Hi. I can say that this is one of the solution but we are not looking for paid add-ons at the moment. Thanks for this